# Perl packed/compiled GUI app does not start/not work?

Tags: perl, winapi, user-interface, pp-perl-par-packager

I'm trying to pack/compile this simple app using [pp](http://search.cpan.org/~autrijus/PAR/script/pp) with `pp --gui -o test.exe test.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Win32::GUI();
use Win32::TieRegistry (Delimiter => "/");
use File::Basename;
use strict;

my $slabel;

my $main = Win32::GUI::Window->new(
    -name   => 'User APP',
    -title  => "User APP",
    -width  => 550,
    -height => 300,
);

$main->Show();
Win32::GUI::Dialog();
exit(0);

sub Main_Terminate {
    return -1;
}
```

However it does not work, it does not start for some reason. Any ideas why?

If I try to compile/pack it using `pp -o test.exe test.pl` then I get the error

> Can't find Win32.pm.

I'm stuck with this.

Comment: I noticed that you link to an outdated version of pp (newest one is always at http://p3rl.org/pp or http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR-Packer/lib/pp.pm), could it be that your problem also stems from running this outdated version? If applicable, please upgrade and try again.

Comment: I was not able to even propery install this latest (http://p3rl.org/pp) version ;/

Comment: Ok, I've installed latest PAR from http://p3rl.org/pp, I was missing (ppm install Getp-ArgvFIle and Module-Scandeps) and it seems to work fine this time ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "pp -M Win32 ..."?  The -M argument adds modules that aren't autodiscovered via the Module::ScanDeps heuristics.